# How to compare an element from an array with an element from a SList?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I am programming a method to show all the employees from a shopping centre:

```
public SList<Empleado> getEmployees(boolean show) {
    SList<Employee> allEmployees = new SList<Employee>();

    for (int i = 0; i < centreEmployees.length; i++) {
        allEmployees.addFirst(centreEmployees[i]);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < shopList.length; j++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < shopList[j].getEmployees().length; x++) {
            allEmployees.addFirst(shopList[j].getEmployees()[x]);
        }
    }

    if (show) {
        for (int i = 0; i < allEmployees.getSize(); i++) {
            System.out.println(allEmployees.getAt(i).toStringE());
        }
    }
    return allEmployees;
}
```

centreEmployees and shopList are two arrays and I would like to compare the employees I add to allEmployees list with the employees I am adding from the `shopList[j].getEmployees()[x]`.

This is because two shops could have the same employees and when I tried to show them, they are showing duplicated and I just want to show them one time.

Comment: If your `SList` class have a contains method, you can use it before adding the employee to the `SList` you build (this won't be very efficient). If you're allowed to use the JDK collections, a `Set` is probably the structure you are looking for.

Comment: What is `toStringE()`?

Comment: @Braj SList is a class which contains methods to interact with that List.
toStringE() is a method that returns the attributes in a String.

Comment: @alexgarciab try with `Set`

Comment: @alexgarciab do you want to maintain the order also?

Comment: @ZouZou thanks. Using the method contains I have solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> they are showing duplicated and I just want to show them one time

Simply try [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html%28%29) that says:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.

You need to provide the logic for equality of the Employee object by overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()` method.

```
class Employee{
      String name;

      public boolean equals(Object o) {
         ...//logic to compare the equality of the Employee object
      }

      public int hashCode() {
         ...
      }

 }
```

---

[HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) internally uses `hashCode()` method to check for equality. If two Employee object generates same hash code then it falls down for `equals()` method to check for equality.

Look at the other implementation of `Set` interface.